# Mongoose: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined, on nested Schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I set up my schema like so:

```
var videoSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    url: String, //Link to the video
    rating: { type: Number, default: 0},
    description: String //a paragraph or two to go along with the video
});

var tutorialPageSchema = new Schema({
    title: String, //IE Peeking, Clutching, etc.
    tutorials: [videoSchema]
});

var categorySchema = new Schema({
    title: String, //intermediate, beginner, config, map knowledge, etc.
    pages: [tutorialPageSchema]
});

exports.Video = mongoose.model('video', videoSchema);
exports.TutorialPage = mongoose.model('tutorialPage', tutorialPageSchema);
exports.Category = mongoose.model('category', categorySchema);
```

Add the document like so:

```
var newPage = new models.TutorialPage({
    title: req.query.page.title,
    tutorials: []
});
parentCategory.pages.push(newPage);
```

In return, it gives me a nice "TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined
"

Other times the question was asked, people didn't load the schemas in the correct order or conflated the Model with the Schema when setting the schema up, but that doesn't seem to be my problem. What gives?

Comment: The parentCategory doesn't have pages property. What is parentCategory and how do you get it.

Comment: models.Category.find({title: req.query.page.category}, function(err, parentCategory){

Comment: What is the output of console.log(parentCategory) ?

Comment: [ { _id: 55407995e230cc0c18326167,
    title: 'Beginner',
    __v: 0,
    pages: [] } ]

I initialized pages with an empty array like I did up there with 'tutorials: []' if that makes any difference.

Comment: You getting an array not an object. You should use findOne if you expect to get only one category. Your current code would work with parentCategory[0].pages.push....

Comment: @Molda zzz facepalm. That's probably it. I'll try it tomorrow. Thanks.